Create Dynamic element only when button is pressed
I have a DynamicModule that looks like this:

Input boxes
Button to create complex UI Element
Complex UI Element

Or with some more detail:
DynamicModule[{input,complexUI},
Column@{
  InputField[Dynamic[input]],
  Button["Make Complex UI", complexUI = makeComplexUI[input]],
  Dynamic[complexUI, TrackedSymbols:>{complexUI}]
},
  Initialization:>(complexUI = "not initialized")
]

I only want complexUI to update when it's created (switch from 'not initialized' to its full definition), which is why I add TrackedSymbols. However, what I'm seeing is complexUI is constantly updating. I can tell because performance is very bad, but if I assign it to localUI (i.e. localUI = complexUI = makeComplexUI[input])and display that localUI outside the DynamicModule it works fine.
How do I write a DynamicModule where complexUI will update but only when the button is pressed?

Issue with locally scoped variables?
If I change complexUI from a locally scoped variable to a global (or within the context) I get much better performance:
DynamicModule[{input (*remove complexUI from DynamicModule*)},
Column@{
  InputField[Dynamic[input]],
  Button["Make Complex UI", complexUI = makeComplexUI[input]],
  Dynamic[complexUI, TrackedSymbols:>{complexUI}]
},
  Initialization:>(complexUI = "not initialized")
]

This works much better (in initial testing). Can someone explain?
